# Use Systemd user services with ecryptfs

Tags: linux, systemd, encryption, ecryptfs

I want accomplish the following task:
On a Ubuntu System with multiple Users accounts and encrypted Home directorys a NFS share should be mounted after login.
I want to use systemd user service for this, but can't get it fully working.

What's working so far:
 - manual mount with user rights, configured with sudo
 - enabling the user service and starting it with `systemctl --user start usermount.service`

After a reboot systemd doesn't even know that this unit exists.
I think there is a problem in combination with an encrypted $HOME (ecryptfs in my case), because the service unit and autostart configuration are located in `.config/systemd/user/`. My assumption is that the systemd user process is started immediatly after login, before decrypting the homedir and hence doesn't see the users configuration.

Whats my possibilities to solve this task?

Comment: I have a similar issue on Arch and came to the same conclusion: “the systemd user process is started immediately after login, before decrypting the homedir and hence doesn't see the users configuration”. I'd also add that it's stopped after unmounting the homedir, so any service which needs to access the homedir at shutdown won't work either. This is even more true when using systemd lingering, which makes user services start after boot, even if the user doesn't log in at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug in the ecryptfs package configuration.
You can use a quick fix:
Open /etc/pam.d/common-session and switch the lines

```
session optional        pam_systemd.so
session optional        pam_ecryptfs.so unwrap
```

to

```
session optional        pam_ecryptfs.so unwrap
session optional        pam_systemd.so
```

so that pam_systemd.so is loaded after pam_ecryptfs.so

Comment: Thanks, that worked!